# Obtener un conjunto de datos de cada usuario

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola amigos necesito ayuda en cómo obtener los 3 resultados mayores de la columna 'resultado' de cada usuario con sus datos correspondientes que se muestran en la tabla, por favor amigos he intentado realizar la siguiente que se muestra abajo y si me trae todos los datos pero yo quiero que me traiga de todos los usuarios no solo de uno bueno según lo que me muestra es de un usuario y en la tabla 'puntajes' a la que le estoy aplicando la consulta tiene dos usuarios. Cómo obtener todos? Es posible obtener de todos? acepto sugerencias y correcciones. Gracias.

Mi consulta:

```
  select nombre_carrera, puntajes.id_alumno, nombre,apellido_pa, apellido_ma, nombre_perfil, resultado from alumno, puntajes, perfil, carrera 
where perfil.id_perfil = puntajes.id_perfil and puntajes.id_alumno = alumno.id_alumno and alumno.id_carrera = carrera.id_carrera order by resultado DESC limit 0,3;
```

La tabla a la que le realizo la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos que obtengo de un solo usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias amigos a todos los que me ayudaron ya logre obtener la consulta hasta aquí logre llegar tal ves no sea muy optimo pero funciona, ya solo nomas la adaptan a sus necesidades :

```
    SELECT nombre, apellido_pa, apellido_ma, nombre_carrera, 
    resultado, puntajes.id_perfil, nombre_perfil FROM perfil, 
    carrera,alumno, puntajes WHERE puntajes.id_perfil = perfil.id_perfil 
    and alumno.id_carrera = carrera.id_carrera and 
alumno.id_alumno = puntajes.id_alumno and puntajes.resultado >= IFNULL((SELECT resultado FROM 
puntajes AS p2 WHERE p2.id_alumno = puntajes.id_alumno ORDER BY resultado DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2), 0) ORDER BY puntajes.id_alumno, resultado DESC
```

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para indicar a la comunidad que esta fue la solución

Comment: listo amigo :).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes a añadir un GROUP BY id de alumno combinado con el mayor resultado para obtener los datos de los alumnos. He supuesto las relaciones con las tablas alumno y carrera.

```
SELECT nombre_carrera, puntajes.id_alumno, nombre,apellido_pa, apellido_ma,  MAX(resultado)
FROM puntajes p
INNER JOIN alumno a ON a.id_alumno = p.id_alumno
INNER JOIN carrera c ON c.id_carrera = a.id_carrera
GROUP BY puntajes.id_alumno 
ORDER BY resultado DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Hola gracias por ayudarme probé la consulta si funciona pero cambiando puntajes.id_alumno por p.id_alumno. Te lo agradezco pero aún no puedo obtener los 3 resultados mas grandes el max solo me trae el numero 1 quiero los 3 primeros de cada usuario es decir de un usuario obtengo sus tres resultados eso es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo implementado con una sola tabla ya que desconozco la organización de las demás tablas.

Esta es la tabla que utilice de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT A.id, MAX(nota) AS nota1,
(SELECT AL.nota FROM alumnos AS AL WHERE AL.id = A.id AND AL.nota <> (SELECT nota FROM alumnos AS AL2 WHERE AL2.id = AL.id ORDER BY nota DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY AL.nota DESC LIMIT 1) AS nota2,
(SELECT AL.nota FROM alumnos AS AL WHERE AL.id = A.id AND AL.nota <> (SELECT nota FROM alumnos AS AL2 WHERE AL2.id = AL.id ORDER BY nota DESC LIMIT 1) AND AL.nota <> ((SELECT AL.nota FROM alumnos AS AL WHERE AL.id = A.id AND AL.nota <> (SELECT nota FROM alumnos AS AL2 WHERE AL2.id = AL.id ORDER BY nota DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY AL.nota DESC LIMIT 1))
ORDER BY AL.nota DESC LIMIT 1) AS nota3
FROM alumnos AS A
GROUP BY A.id
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La alternativa sí utilizas una versión de MariaDB mas actualizada o MySQL Server propiamente dicho sería:

```
SELECT A.id, MAX(nota) AS nota1,
(SELECT AL.nota FROM alumnos AS AL WHERE AL.id = A.id AND AL.nota <> (SELECT nota FROM alumnos AS AL2 WHERE AL2.id = AL.id ORDER BY nota DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY AL.nota DESC LIMIT 1) AS nota2,
(SELECT AL.nota FROM alumnos AS AL WHERE AL.id = A.id AND AL.nota NOT IN (SELECT nota FROM alumnos AS AL2 WHERE AL2.id = AL.id ORDER BY AL2.nota DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY AL.nota DESC LIMIT 1) AS nota3
FROM alumnos AS A
GROUP BY A.id
```

El problema es que:

> Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'

Sí vamos a la vida real esto sería mas fácil con un lenguaje auxiliar PHP, Java, etc. O hasta dentro del mismo MySQL utilizando un procedimiento almacenado, toda consulta poder se puede realizar pero a veces resulta muy engorroso resolverlo solo con MySQL.

Para implementar el código anterior, solo deberás realizar los JOINS correspondientes donde sea necesario. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias amigo, solo una pregunta ¿Esta consulta no se tarda mucho en miles de registros? porfa me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Hola, un ejemplo bajo que contexto ? Ya esta el ejemplo con la entrada y salida en el comentario.
Posiblemente no sea la consulta mas óptima, seguramente exista una alternativa.

Comment: amigo tu tabla alumnos cuantos registros  tiene?